# How to get the current CPU usage and available memory in batch file?

Tags: batch-file, cpu-usage, ram

I am creating a simple script that outputs the current user logged in, CPU usage for the current system and the available memory?

I have managed to get the current user/s logged on but is it possible to get the cpu usage and memory as well?

This is my code so far.

```
@echo off

for /f "tokens=3 delims=\" %%i in ("%USERPROFILE%") do (set USER=%%i) 2>&1  
echo "Logged On User: %USER%"  
echo. 

pause
```

To get the cpu usage i have tried this command but it doesn't seem to be working.

```
for /f "skip=1" %p in ('wmic cpu get loadpercentage') do 
echo %p%
```

Comment: What is leading you to believe that it is not working? Are you getting an error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could always utilise the `systeminfo` command, but then would be forced to go through a brief loading screen

```
set totalMem=
set availableMem=
set usedMem=
REM You need to make a loop
for /f "tokens=4" %%a in ('systeminfo ^| findstr Physical') do if defined totalMem (set availableMem=%%a) else (set totalMem=%%a)
set totalMem=%totalMem:,=%
set availableMem=%availableMem:,=%
set /a usedMem=totalMem-availableMem
Echo Total Memory: %totalMem%
Echo Used Memory: %usedMem%
```

And that should do exactly what you want. This code can easily be modified to show Virtual Memory as well. (The use of `set totalMem=%totalMem:,=%` and `set availableMem=%availableMem:,=%` gets rid of commas in the variables.)

Mona

Comment: thanks, it works, except, the used memory is a little inaccurate. for example, if the used memory is 1.8, it displays 2 and also, i realised that the total memory is display like "x,xxx". when calculating the used memory wouldn't the comma cause problems?

Comment: yea, but fixing that is easy

Comment: sorry, i am new to batch, how would you fix it?

Answer (score 8):

Firstly, when running from a batch file, the for loop variable needs two percentage symbols - `%%p`

Secondly, you need to echo `%%p`, not `%p%`:

```
for /f "skip=1" %%p in ('wmic cpu get loadpercentage') do echo %%p
```

From the command line:

```
for /f "skip=1" %p in ('wmic cpu get loadpercentage') do echo %p
```

Answer (score 0):

```
typeperf "\processor(_Total)\% Processor Time"  -SC 1 -y
```

or

```
C:\>logman create counter CPU_Usage3 -c "\Processor(_Total)\% Processor Time" -f csv -o %temp%\cpu.csv
The command completed successfully.

C:\>logman start CPU_Usage3
The command completed successfully.

C:\>logman stop CPU_Usage3
The command completed successfully.

C:\>type %temp%\cpu*.csv
The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Typeperf is not available for WindowsXP home ,but logman requires admin privileges and creates a temp file. [TYPEPERF](http://ss64.com/nt/typeperf.html) . [LOGMAN](http://ss64.com/nt/logman.html) . For the memory check these counters:
http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-performance-counters.html

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set Times=0

for /f "skip=1" %%p in ('wmic cpu get loadpercentage') do (

set Cpusage!Times!=%%p

set /A Times=!Times! + 1

)

echo Percentage = %Cpusage0%

pause
```

Comment: How can I the store multiple output of this `wmic cpu get loadpercentage, name, status` in multiple variables