# how to find the percentage of CPU, RAM And memory usage using Batch FIle

Tags: cmd

I want o display the percentage of CPU usage and percentage of Free CPU,
And same for RAM And running program with date and time stamp

```
@echo off 
Powershell -command "&{Get-WmiObject -Query 'Select * from Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfProc_Process '| Select Name, @{Name='CPU(p)';Expression={$_.PercentProcessorTime}} | where {$_.'CPU(p)' -gt 0 } |Sort 'CPU(p)' -descending | Format-Table -AutoSize;}" 
Powershell -command "&{Get-Process | Select Name, @{Name='CPU(s)';Expression={$_.CPU}} | sort 'CPU(s)' -Descending | Select -First 5| Format-Table -AutoSize;}"
 Powershell -noexit -command "&{Get-WmiObject -Query 'Select * from Win32_OperatingSystem' | Select FreePhysicalMemory | Format-Table -AutoSize;}
```

I tried Above code but i want the output like CPU  % Utilized    % Free, RAM  % utilized   % Free,  Program  %CPU  % RAM

Comment: What you have tried and where you are failing?

Comment: @echo off
Powershell -command "&{Get-WmiObject -Query 'Select * from Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfProc_Process '| Select Name, @{Name='CPU(p)';Expression={$_.PercentProcessorTime}} | where {$_.'CPU(p)' -gt 0 } |Sort 'CPU(p)' -descending | Format-Table -AutoSize;}"
Powershell -command "&{Get-Process | Select Name, @{Name='CPU(s)';Expression={$_.CPU}} | sort 'CPU(s)' -Descending | Select -First 5| Format-Table -AutoSize;}"
Powershell -noexit -command "&{Get-WmiObject -Query 'Select * from Win32_OperatingSystem' | Select FreePhysicalMemory | Format-Table -AutoSize;}"

Comment: add the code to the question with formatting.

Comment: but i want output like CPU   % Utilized    % Free,  RAM   % Utilized   % free  ,  program  % CPU  %RAM

Comment: Add these detail to question to get help faster.

Comment: If you search you can find answer in existing StackOverflow questions.

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20208373/how-to-get-the-current-cpu-usage-and-available-memory-in-batch-file

Comment: i used that but gives the output like this

Comment: C:\utils>for/f "tokens=4" %a in ('systeminfo | findstr Physical') do if defined
totalMem (set availableMem=%a) else (set totalMem=%a)
'for' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\utils>set totalMem=,=

C:\utils>set availableMem=,=

C:\utils>set /a usedMem=totalMem-availableMem

C:\utils>Echo Total Memory: ,=
Total Memory: ,=

Comment: There is space between for and /f

Comment: after giving the space it gives output like this                                                   
C:\utils>set totalMem=

C:\utils>set availableMem=

C:\utils>set usedMem=

C:\utils>for /F "tokens=4" %a in ('systeminfo | findstr Physical') do if defined
 totalMem (set availableMem=%a )  else (set totalMem=%a )
Loading Hotfix Information ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
@echo off

set totalMem=
set availableMem=
set usedMem=
for /f "tokens=4" %%a in ('systeminfo ^| findstr Physical') do if defined totalMem (set availableMem=%%a) else (set totalMem=%%a)

set totalMem=%totalMem:,=%

set availableMem=%availableMem:,=%

set /a usedMem=totalMem-availableMem

Echo Total Memory: %totalMem%
Echo Used Memory: %usedMem%



setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set Times=0

for /f "skip=1" %%p in ('wmic cpu get loadpercentage') do (

set Cpusage!Times!=%%p

set /A Times=!Times! + 1

)

echo Percentage = %Cpusage0%
```

Source: [How to get the current CPU usage and available memory in batch file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20208373/how-to-get-the-current-cpu-usage-and-available-memory-in-batch-file)

Comment: Thanks For Answer I also want the RAM percentage and running program utilization